# Formal definition of linear span(help to visualize)

Tags: linear-algebra

The definition of linear span: given a vector space V over a field K, the span of a set S of vectors (not necessarily finite) is defined to be the intersection W of all subspaces of V that contain S.

This is the formal definition of linear span and I feel difficulties to visualize it with the help of set notation. 
Can you give me concrete example with V,W and S?

Comment: The idea is to take the "smallest" vector space that contain all your vectors (from $S$). This is achieved by taking this intersection.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An equivalent definition of $\textrm{span}(S)$ is the set $\{c_1v_1 + \cdots + c_nv_n|c_i \in K, v_i \in S\}$ consisting of all linear combinations of elements of $S.$ I think of this as "all vectors you can build using (scalar multiples of) the vectors in $S$."

The span of the set $\{0\}$ in any vector space is again simply $\{0\}.$ In fact, this is a special case of the observation that the span of a vector subspace $W$ is again $W,$ since subspaces are closed under taking linear combinations.

The span of $\{v\},$ where $v$ is a non-zero vector, is the unique line containing $v.$ For example, $\textrm{span}(\{(1,0)\}) \subset \mathbb{R}^2$ is the $x$-axis. Notice that $\textrm{span}(\{(1,0), (2,0)\}) \subset \mathbb{R}^2$ is again the $x$-axis, since $(1,0)$ and $(2,0)$ are scalar multiples of each other. However, $\textrm{span}(\{(1,0),(0,1)\}) \subset \mathbb{R}^2$ is the whole plane -- clearly we can construct any vector $(a,b)$ as $a(1,0) + b(0,1).$

Answer (score 0):

Not being a mathematician, I find QR decomposition helps me the most. If $A$ is a $n$ by $m$ matrix with its columns the elements (vectors) of $S$, then QR decomposition of $A$ returns an $n$ by $n$ orthonormal matrix $Q$ that spans all of $V$. The first $m$ columns are basis vectors of $S$. The remaining columns are basis vectors of the space of $V$ not in $S$. Any vector that has a non-zero dot product with any of the basis vectors of $S$ is in the $S$ subspace. Not sure what $W$ is.