# Equivalence of definitions of linear span

Tags: linear-algebra

I have two definition of **linear span**:

**Definition 1**

The *linear span* of a nonempty set $S\subset V$ is defined by
$$
\text{span}(S) =\left\{\sum_{i=1}^nx^i v_i \mid 
n\in\mathbb{N},\ x^i\in\mathbb{F},\ v_i\in S\right\}.
$$

**Definition 2**

Given the subset $S$ of a vector space $V$,

$$
\text{span}(S):=\bigcap\{W \mid (W\text{ subspace of }V)\land (S\subset W)\}.
$$

> How do I prove that the two definitions are equivalent?
>   A sketch or some idea would be, I hope, enough.

The equivalence is mentioned in the question [Formal definition of linear span](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2188046), but no prove is given.

The books I'm using have the following:

1. Greub1975 speaks only of *System of generators* for the vector space and
   does not address the definition of linear span
2. Brown1988 use def. 2 and affirms the equivalence in a Th. 1.15(a). The "Proof" is: "it follows directly from the definition of the linear span."
3. Roman2008 uses def. 1 and I think that in Th. 1.7 he makes the connection to the other definition. But he does not use the expression of intersection of subspaces that are supersets.

Comment: If you prove that the first definition, i.e. the set of all possible (finite, of course) linear combinations of elements of $\;S\;$ is a subspace of $\;V\;$ then you have more than half the proof...Can you see why?

Comment: I think because it is closed under addition and scalar multiplication? you mean basically that span(S) is a subspace and it include S. We would have proven that span2(S)$\subset$span1(S)

Comment: ok, and span2(S) contains S, and span2(S) is a vectorspace (intersection of v.s. is v.s, already proven), thus span1(S)$\subset$span2(S)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's call them $\;D_1,\,D_2\;$ (Definition 1, definition 2, corr.) . If you already proved that $\;D_1\;$ is a subspace, then, as it clearly contains $\;S\;$ , $\;D_1\;$ is one of the subspaces appearing in the definition of $\;D_2\;$ , and thus $\;D_2\subset D_1\;$ .

OTOH, any subspace $\;W\;$ containing $\;S\;$ must contain **any** linear combination of its elements, thus $\;D_1\subset W\;$ ... End the argument now.

Comment: thank you. just a note on the second part: the proof is needed, that intersection of subspaces is a subspace, isn't it?

Comment: @LiPo Yes indeed, though that is usually known before hand. Otherwise, prove it: it is **very** easy.